# Calculating a correction factor for a cylinder with multiple cut-outs

Tags: geometry, volume

I've a base cylinder which the volume is given by:

$$V_{cyl} = \pi r_1^2h \tag{1} $$

where $r_1^2$ is the radius of the cylinder and $h$ is its height.

I want to keep the volume of my geometry while adding cut-offs to it, like shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8KAj.jpg). To do so I imagined that I could add two correcting factors, but I'm confused on how to approach this. Let's call the correcting factor of the height $\alpha$ and for the radius $\gamma$.

For some mechanical needs I can fully cut the cylinder, so I've added a small height $h_{low}$ to it, where I have the volume of that part to be:

$$V_{low} = \pi r^2_1h_{low} \tag{2}$$

There are two questions that got me highly confused. The first one is how I calculate the volume of the geometry in terms of the variables shown in the pictures: $h$, $h_{low}$, $h_{high}$, $r_1$, $r_2$, $cut_w$. The second is that I want $\alpha$ to be a function of $\gamma$ so that $\gamma$ multiples $r_1$, increasing the overall cylinder radius to compensate the lateral cuts created by $cut_w$. Then $\alpha$ multiples $h$ to compensate the middle perforation, using $\gamma r_1$ already.

Is something like that possible? How I can do this?

I hope my question formulation was good enough, I'll try to improve it based on feedback given. Thank you in advance

**EDIT**:

What I came up with is to first calculate $\alpha$ using making (3) equal to (1) which will make $\alpha$ be as shown in (4). This is considering only a single perforation like in [this case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1SQm.jpg).

$$V_{perCyl} = \pi (r_1^2 - r_2^2)\alpha h + \pi r_2^2h_{low} \tag{3}$$

$$\alpha = \frac{r_1^2h-r_2^2h_{low}}{(r_1^2 - r_2^2)h} \tag{4}$$

Then adding the four cuts I can write the volume (considering the $\gamma$) like shown in (5).

$$V_{finalCyl} = \pi (\gamma r_1^2 - r_2^2)\alpha h+ \pi r_2^2h_{low} - 4 (cut_w(\alpha h - h_{low})(\gamma r1-r2)) \tag{5}$$

Now I need to then make (5) equal to (3) and find $\gamma$ which should take me awhile. If anyone can confirm the logic is correct it'd be nice.

**EDIT2**:

I used matlab to solve this which yield that gamma can be expressed as in (6)

$$\gamma = \frac{(4cut_wr_2(h_{low} - \alpha h) + \pi\alpha h r_2^2 + \pi\alpha h(r_1^2 - r2^2))}{(4cut_wr_1^2(h_{low} - \alpha h) + \pi \alpha h r_1^2)}
 \tag{6}$$

Comment: You could imagine that you have the original cylinder and cut it into the four pieces and than move them away. This is different from the problem you describe. The question if the suggested approach to create the cuts is acceptable? the only parameter in any case is the modification in radius.

Comment: Hi Moti, see the edits I made. I think this is a way to approach the problem in a better way but I'm not sure if it is possible (it was your answer that gave me the idea, so thanks!)